# Why the URL doesn't show the current page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

App.js‏‏:

```
import AllMeetupPage from "./TODos/pages/AllMeetups";
import FavoritsPage from "./TODos/pages/Favorits";
import NewMeetupPage from "./TODos/pages/NewMeetup";
import {Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <Routes>
      <Route path='/allmeetups'>
        <AllMeetupPage/>
      </Route>
      <Route path='/favorits'>
        <FavoritsPage/>
      </Route>
      <Route path='/newmeetups'>
        <NewMeetupPage/>
      </Route>
       </Routes>
    </div>);
  }

  export default App;
```

index.js‏‏:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

NewMeetupPage‏‏.js:

```
function NewMeetupPage(){
    return <div>NewMeetupPage</div>
}

export default NewMeetupPage;
```

[As you can see, "NewMeetupPage" as writen in the div above is not apear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b9kl.png)

On "FavoritsPage " and "AllMeetupPage " the code is the same as NewMeetupPage
Just the text inside the div is different

Comment: Add a / before? Its the only difference... assuming the other 2 do work

Comment: I am editing my code and question right now, it still not working as well as the other 2

Comment: so none are working? any errors in the console?

Comment: None even one..

Answer (score 0):

In the version 6 of React Router Dom, you would use the `element` property of `Route` to render the pages:

```js
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/allmeetups" element={<AllMeetupPage />} />
        <Route path="/favorits" element={<FavoritsPage />} />
        <Route path="newmeetups" element={<NewMeetupPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```